# Adding abline to augPred plot

Tags: r, multi-level, mixed-models

apologies for what is likely to be a very basic question, I am very new to R.

I am looking to read off my augPred plot in order to average out the values to provide a prediction between a time period.

```
> head(tthm.groupeddata)
Grouped Data: TTHM ~ Yearmon | WSZ_Code
  WSZ_Code Treatment_Code Year Month TTHM CL2_FREE    BrO3 Colour  PH  TURB  Yearmon
1        2              3 1996     1 30.7     0.35 0.00030   0.75 7.4 0.055 Jan 1996
2        6              1 1996     2 24.8     0.25 0.00055   0.75 6.9 0.200 Feb 1996
3        7              4 1996     2 60.4     0.05 0.00055   0.75 7.1 0.055 Feb 1996
4        7              4 1996     2 58.1     0.15      NA   0.75 7.5 0.055 Feb 1996  
5        7              4 1996     3 62.2     0.20      NA   2.00 7.6 0.055 Mar 1996
6        5              2 1996     3 40.3     0.15 0.00140   2.00 7.7 0.055 Mar 1996
```

> 

This is my model:

```
modellme<- lme(TTHM ~ Yearmon, random = ~ 1|WSZ_Code, data=tthm.groupeddata)
```

and my current plot:

```
plot(augPred(modellme, order.groups=T),xlab="Date", ylab="TTHM concentration", main="TTHM Concentration with Time for all Water Supply Zones")
```

I would like a way to read off the graph by either placing lines between a specific time period in a specific WSZ_Code (my group) and averaging the values between this period...

Of course any other way/help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: also - if this is entirely incorrect please do let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can tell whether it is "entirely incorrect", since you have not described the question and have not included any data. (The plotting question is close to being entirely incorrect, though.) I can tell you that the answer is NOT to use `abline`, since augPred objects are plotted with `plot.augPred` which returns (and plots) a lattice object. `abline` is a base graphic function and does not share a coordinate system with the lattice device. Lattice objects are lists that can be modified. Your plot probably had different panels at different levels of WSZ_Code, but the location of the desired lines is entirely unclear especially since you trail off with an ellipsis. You refer to "times" but there is no "times" variable.

There are lattice functions such as `trellis.focus` and `update.trellis` that allow one to apply modifications to lattice objects. You would first assign the plot object to a named variable, make mods to it and then plot() it again.

```
help(package='lattice')
?Lattice
```

(If this is a rush job, you might be better off making any calculations by hand and using ImageMagick to edit pdf or png output.)

Comment: Ok, thank you - will have a look. Sorry for not being clear, I did say I am very new to R!